# Reload fail - Ubuntu 15.04 - SSL PassPhrase init

Tags: ssl, key, apache2, reload, passphrase

I got this error on apache2 in my logs when typing:
`/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

*[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437078 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] AH02580: Init: Pass phrase incorrect for key www.XXX.com:443:0

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437128 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437137 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437143 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437150 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437157 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437163 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437169 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437174 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information

[Tue Feb 14 15:53:59.437177 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15072] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key www.XXX.com:443:0, check /root/www.XXXX.com.key

AH00016: Configuration Failed*

Please note that `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` works well.

I created my key on the server using:
`genrsa -des3 -out www.XXXX.com 2048` + password

I created the csr using:
`req -new -key la_cle -out the_file`

The default site configuration are **000-default.conf** and **default-ssl.conf** files:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

*# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet*

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.XXXX.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/www.XXXX.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/www.XXXX.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /root/inter.www.XXXX.com.crt
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
    #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

    #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
    #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
    #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
    #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
    #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
    #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

    #   Client Authentication (Type):
    #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
    #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
    #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
    #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   SSL Engine Options:
    #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
    #   o FakeBasicAuth:
    #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
    #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
    #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
    #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
    #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
    #   o ExportCertData:
    #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
    #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
    #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
    #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
    #    into CGI scripts.
    #   o StdEnvVars:
    #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
    #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
    #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
    #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
    #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
    #   o OptRenegotiate:
    #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
    #    directives are used in per-directory context.
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
    #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
    #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
    #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
    #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
    #    This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
    #    SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
    #    the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
    #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
    #    mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
    #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
    #    This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
    #    SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
    #    alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
    #    practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
    #    this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
    #    works correctly.
    #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
    #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
    #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
    #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

*# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet*

In the **apache2.conf** file I made a script with the password `SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/root/key-pem`.

I can't get why it doesn't work.

Comment: Try again and in English.

Comment: I kindly tried to translate it for you: on your next post please consider using English, otherwise people won't even read your questions.

Comment: SSLPassPhraseDialog should be the path to a program which should return the pass phrase for the protected key on stdout. You instead simple use the protected key as argument which will not work and thus you get the error. For the details [read the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslpassphrasedialog).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the French part. I don't think the problem is coming from my script I pass to sslpassdialogphrase because if I'm kicking that away and I typed the password by hand it's still not working. Plus I have the configuration on another server that does the same and it works.
The problem is always the same. There is a mismatch value on www.xxxx.com.key and I can't figure why. 
I tried to create my own self certificate and it works. If there was the same problem from my self signed certificate then maybe i would have mistyped the passphrase before but seems like I didn't..